# Stop ios from auto centering input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, css

I used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

to stop ios from auto-zooming in to a input field, but it's still centering the input field in the middle of the page. How do I fix this? I also tried using:

```
function moveBack() {
var middle = window.innerWidth/4;
window.scrollTo(middle,0);
}
```

onclick of the input field, but it's also not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use the search function here, two questions you have asked today have been duplicates

Comment: @cmorrissey You think I have not already tried those? It didn't work for me. Which is why I'm asking this.